# win.document is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have strane issue with IE 11 where some strange strings "Undefined" displayed on the page. Please find the attached screen shot of the code and also the source code for yoru reference.

i doubt the var win = open_Link4.. should be the culprit. Open_Link4 is returning the windows object.

Please provide me the solution at the earliest.

```
writer.print("<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"var win = open_link4('', 'notesAddWin");
writer.print(claimNumber); 
writer.print("', 650, 700); if( win.document == undefined || 
win.document.forms[0] == undefined || "); 
writer.print("win.document.forms[0].claimNumber == undefined || win.document.forms[0].claimNumber.value != '");
```

Comment: on win variable i'm calling again win.document == undefined ...

Comment: Share the image pls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to have

```
window.document
```

or

```
window
```

or

```
document
```

IE says (sometimes) truth, there is no global *win* variable in JS. Unless you have defined it somewhere else.
Here is the ref:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

After review:

1. You are execurint onclick wrong, you should put there function call only secondly you have missed quotes there.

   ```
   ... onclick=\"open_link4('', 'notesAddWin');\" ...
   ```
2. How to get form from DOM:

   ```
   document.forms[0]
   ```

You should destroy your win variable, it is making a bit of a mess

Comment: Pls also share the picture, because I think you had not saw the preview of your post:)

Comment: i'm not able to post the picture due to reputation count. pardon my ignorance

Comment: Ok, so then can you check if my guess was correct? What did you expect to get from win variable? Secondly this is a javascript variable, not jQuery, you are missing javascript tag then.

Comment: Share the code pls. Put it in your question, and format it, if you could:)

Comment: writer.print("<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"var win = open_link4('', 'notesAddWin");
   writer.print(claimNumber);
   writer.print("', 650, 700); if( win.document == undefined || win.document.forms[0] == undefined || ");
   writer.print("win.document.forms[0].claimNumber == undefined || win.document.forms[0].claimNumber.value != '");

Comment: writer.print("<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"var win = open_link4('', 'notesAddWin");
   writer.print(claimNumber);
   writer.print("', 650, 700); if( win.document == undefined || win.document.forms[0] == undefined || ");
   writer.print("win.document.forms[0].claimNumber == undefined || win.document.forms[0].claimNumber.value != '");
   writer.print(claimNumber);
   writer.print("' ) { open_link4('");
   writer.print(LinkManager.getLink("ICSAddNote"));
   writer.print("?claimNumber=");
   ...
   writer.print("', 650, 700) } \">Add Note</a><br />");

Comment: Ok, so I assume you wanted to put HTML code to your page using Js, yes?

Comment: S you are right. the same code is working absolutely fine in IE 8 but in IE 11 we are getting some unwanted string "Undefined" on our page.

Comment: since open_Link4 is returning Windows object, do we need to type cast the variable win like windows.win = open_link4? absolutely no idea on the issue . find the code sample for open_LInk4 below.

Comment: function open_link4(URL, windowId, winWidth, winHeight) {
 var adjTop = 10;
 var adjLeft = (screen.width - winWidth) - 10; 
 
 var options = "width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight +            
  ",scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,left=" + adjLeft + ",top=" + adjTop + ",menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,history=no";
   var textWinName = new String(windowId);
 var newWindow = window.open(URL,textWinName,options);
 newWindow.focus();
 return newWindow;
}

Comment: First of all your code is a hell of a mess, extract all your JS code to a function, then use only that function call, do not use such code in real life, it is a very bad habbit. Secondly, you have missed few ' and ", and your code does not even compile. It's because it is not clean, you have misex too many Js insode DOM, JS must be always extracted to a file and kept there.

Comment: Beri, thanks for yoru suggestions and actually I'm new to this project (Just 2 weeks) and almost gap of 5 years I returned to JAVA stream. since I have given pieces of code snippets,it might look like hell at the first instance. since the limitation on the content here, we are not able to give complete code for your reference.

Comment: But you could easilly print that snipplet to your question, there are almoust no limitations there, and it would make our work much easyer:) In my guess, extract that code to a script, and then renew this question, I will happily help.